# Codecademy, Python code won't work

Tags: python

I have started programming in Python at Codecademy. So far I think that I've learn some basic programming skill and I'm really existed to try something more difficult.

On a project I've been working I keep getting this error
My code looks like this:

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input("What's your name?")

def function():

    if len(original) > 0:
        print original
    else:
        print "empty"
```

The task is to see if the string is empty cause I will be using this piece of code later on. 
When I press the 'Save & Submit Code' it prompts with my question and I type my answer in to the editor, and then nothing happens.

The message I get is: "The original variable ("Nicolai") had more than 0 characters but did not get printed."

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: So do you execute the function?

Comment: Although not a keyword, but "function" is a really really bad name for a function. I know that you are a complete beginner, but learning good coding conventions from the start is always a good thing. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you're ever calling the function, only defining it. Try inserting:

```
function()
```

at the end. (also please name it more descriptively than "function")

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the exercise, it doesn't want you to create a function. Simply remove the `def function():` (and don't forget to un-indent your code!)

In fact, learning functions is after the PygLatin course :D

Comment: Alright :D                                                                 It's just that all the script where if, elif, else and where include there were always a [def function():]